# Implementing an OAuth2 authorization server with CXF

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, cxf

I would like to implement an OAuth2 authorization server ONLY (no resource) with CXF 3.
The goal is to get a token I can use on my separate resource server.
I have already spent hours trying to find good doc or tutorial with no success.

Here is what I coded so far:
**cxf.xml**

```
<bean id="oauthProvider" class="com.mycompany.OAuthDataProviderImpl"/>

<bean id="accessTokenService" class="org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.AccessTokenService">
    <property name="dataProvider" ref="oauthProvider"/>
</bean>

<bean id="authorizationService" class="org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.AuthorizationCodeGrantService">
    <property name="dataProvider" ref="oauthProvider"/>
</bean>

<jaxrs:server id="oauthServer" address="/oauth">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="accessTokenService"/>
        <ref bean="authorizationService"/>          
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My **OAuthDataProviderImpl** class extends AbstractOAuthDataProvider and implements OAuthDataProvider and contains this method:

```
@Override
public Client getClient(String clientId) throws OAuthServiceException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(">>>>> getClient");
    return null;
}
```

When I run the server and try to load
/oauth/authorize?client_id=123456789&scope=scopeTest7&response_type=code&redirect_uri=someUrl&state=1
I get, in the console

DEBUG o.a.c.s.invoker.AbstractInvoker - Invoking method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.RedirectionBasedGrantService.authorize() on object org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.AuthorizationCodeGrantService@2bb3be89 with params [].
WARN  o.a.c.j.i.WebApplicationExceptionMapper - javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException: **HTTP 401 Unauthorized**

">>>>> getClient" doesn't appear in the logs, getClient() from OAuthDataProviderImpl isn't supposed to be called?

Please let me know if something is missing from the xml config file or web.xml, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Been messing with CXF OAuth2 myself. And it seems like you are not sending the HTTP basic auth header. That will reject the request as that is where the Client ID and secret is supposed to come from.